# rest api, normalize mysql returned row data in php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm new to PHP, I learn it less than 3 days, I'm stuck, I came from #C background. Below is the result of my row.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rowult)) {
    echo json_encode($row);
}

//result of echo json_encode($row);
{"id":"1","name":"john","blood_type_id":"1","value": 213,"blood_name":"dog"}{"id":"1","name":"john","blood_type_id":"2","value": 888,"blood_name":"bat"}
```

What's the best way to build a json like this?

```
[{
    "id":1,
    "name":"john",
    "blood":[{blood_type_id: 1},{value:213},{blood_name:"dog"},
             {blood_type_id: 2},{value:888},{blood_name:"bat"}]
}]
```

Comment: In MySql5.7 and later you can save your data in unstructured type that called JSON. you can save full json string and query for subset of this json if you need.

Comment: @4EACH but now I have to output this simple api structure. How would you normally do it? I'm not a php guy, I need help :(

Comment: @GlobinHughes your data format is simple enough, however your specification for output makes no sense to me.  If i were using a service whose api gave me some result in that format, my first priority would be to find another source.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg you think my spec is nonsense? have you ever since any api that produce duplicated object like this? `{"id":"1","name":"john","blood_type_id":"1","value": 213,"blood_name":"dog"}{"id":"1","name":"john","blood_type_id":"2","value": 888,"blood_name":"bat"}` Just assume this is a person list, he will have diferent blood types, so how would you structure the data?

Answer (score 2):

You need to create an array and assign each data first and then at last encode it:-

Do like below:-

```
$final_array = [];// create an array
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rowult)) {
    $final_array[$row['name']]['id'] = $row['id']; // use name as key so that same name records will come inside single-array 
    $final_array[$row['name']]['name'] = $row['name']; // assign values to array 
    $final_array[$row['name']]['blood'][] = [['blood_type_id'=>$row['blood_type_id']],['value'=>$row['value']],['blood_name'=>$row['blood_name']]]; // since you need `blood` as an array so create a key blood an assign values to them like an array
}

$final_array = array_values($final_array); // now remove name indexes

echo json_encode($final_array); // final encoded data
```

A hard-coded sample example output:-https://eval.in/928775

Comment: is this how PHP dude always do their data restructuring? this common thing sounds like so complicated.

Comment: print_r can't give me what I want, how to make it in json? I need javascript to read it.

Comment: @GlobinHughes  check that edited solution. I have change it for what you asked

Comment: many thanks, now the code look much better and readable. But I'm still curious is this how you normally restructure the data after fetch from db? I'm stuck at doing simple thing with php haha.

Comment: @MadelineRies   i aslos learned by practicing it and it takes time. So try to practice every-day

Comment: @GlobinHughes   did you tried updated code? Problem solved or not?